# 'uintmax_t': is not a member of '`global namespace''

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017, leveldb

I am trying to rebuild the leveldb implementation
https://github.com/chirino/leveldb

in visual studio 2017 as the existing release is built with 2010.

Getting a strange compile error while building it in VS 2017

I downloaded the code from the latest tag, and imported the project in VS2017, converted it to VS 2017 and tried to compile.

Getting the following

```
Error   C2039   'uintmax_t': is not a member of '`global namespace''    leveldb c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\cstdint 54
```

This error is occuring in the standard VC++ file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\cstdint

```
using _CSTD uintmax_t; using _CSTD uintptr_t;
```

This is the line in the cstdint file of windows

Can anyone please help me with this error ?
I am trying to make the leveldb compatible with VS2017 runtime, and trying to remove the dependency with VS2010 runtime. Hence i am in the process of building leveldb first and then fusesource leveldb-jni and camel level db.

Comment: Which header is included in the code, `cstdint` or `stdint.h`? If it's the former `uintmax_t` must be prefixed with `std::`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the error is occuring the cstdint file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include\.

Comment: Be sure to compile with the c++11 standard, check the project settings.

Comment: Why use that old forked variant of LevelDB instead of [the original](https://github.com/google/leveldb)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude because that is included in https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni and which in turn is used in camel-leveldb. My java application at the end uses camel-leveldb, which internally uses chirino leveldb fork. And i am trying to make my application run with VS2017 runtime instead of VS2010 runtime

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i set the C++14 and C++17 standard in the project properties , still no use. There is no option for C++11. Would that matter ?

Comment: A software, depending on a software, depending on a software, adapted to an old compiler (which is known to be incompliant to C++ of any standard)... has to be adapted to a compiler which is, at least, more compliant to newer C++ standards... This doesn't sound to me like to become a "success story". May be, the hint of @Someprogrammerdude was not that bad to fall back to "the original". If this causes some adjustments in the other projects, you finally even could provide a "pull request" or fork with resp. up-to-date versions.

Answer (score 0):

For common processors the best solution is to modify cstdint file by setting

`typedef int8_t  int_least8_t;`
....

instead of

```
using _CSTD int_least8_t;
```

i uploaded the modified cstdint file to

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lmMjNLBgvH_cLwE0INsAFzJvd5nC49ya/view?usp=sharing